# How can I read a certain row from a range to infinity on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm learning google apps script and making a sales project. I want to be able to read a certain column from a single cell into infinity (A1:infinity range for example). getRange functions only work if I give them an endpoint, how can I get around that?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
function readAllOfTheDataInAColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow());
  const vs = rg.getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Spreadsheet.getRange()` and `Sheet.getRange()` methods work fine with open-ended ranges. You can get the values in column `C2:C` until the last row in the spreadsheet with something like this:

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const values = ss.getRange('Sheet1!C2:C').getValues();
```

To remove blank values, use this pattern:

```
  const values = ss.getRange('Sheet1!C2:C').getValues()
    .flat()
    .filter(value => value !== '');
```

Note that this gives a 1D array rather than a 2D array.

Comment: The question explicitly specifies _"from a single cell into infinity (A1:infinity range for example)"_.

Comment: I don't think you can get just the non-blank values in a column without filtering of some kind, because `Sheet.getLastRow()` does not look at a column but a sheet. An individual column may have any number of blanks above that row.

Comment: While I see this working, I had not thought about the infinite null cells. But thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to remove blank values.